# Problem on square with vertex on a hyperbola

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the equation $\frac{x^2} {3}-\frac {y^2} {12}=1 $ and a square with vertices on the hyperbola and sides parallel to the axis prove that every vertex has this property:

Let $A$ be the vertex, and $r$ the tangent to the hyperbola in the point $A$. If $M, N$ are the intersection of $r$ with the asymptotes $y=2x$ and $y=-2x$ than $MA\cong NA$.

I don't know how to prove this fact, is it general?
How many square of this type are there?

Comment: A square with its vertices on the hyperbola centered on the origin must have those vertices on the lines $ \ y = x \ $ and $ \ y = -x \ $ .  If you use those in the equation of the hyperbola, you'll have the coordinates of the vertices and will see how many possible squares there could be.  Shouldn't the asymptotes be $ \ y = \pm \ 2 x \ $ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right , thanks. I think your hint is enought i'm gonna try to complete the exercise.

Comment: Also, have you had calculus or not?  There is a quick way to get the equation of the tangent line to the hyperbola by differentiation, and a slower way using algebra alone.

Comment: It is supposed to be a problem for high school. So it is not a general fact from symmetries?

Comment: I'll confess that the analytical proof was so straightforward that I hadn't considered a purely geometric argument (and since you used an analytic-geometry tag, I assumed that's what you were looking for).  But since the figure has four-fold symmetry, you can probably form a proof by looking at what goes on with the other vertices of the square and the various  intersection points.  (Then you don't need to know exactly what the tangent-line slopes are.)